# Escaped characters (of form &AOk- for «é») in IMAP4 list response, using IMAP4_SSL in Python

Tags: python, base64, imap, imaplib, utf-7

I am using Python's `imaplib` module, specifically the `IMAP4_SSL` class to get emails from a server.

When I download messages, non-unicode characters are usually escaped as quoted printable escape codes for which I use the `quopri` module.

When I use the `list` method of the `IMAP4_SSL` object however, non-ascii characters are escaped as `<ampersand> some three letter code <dash>`, which looks like this:

```
(\HasNoChildren) "/" "Lib&AOk-rations/Lib&AOk-ration Bilan"
(\HasNoChildren) "/" "Poly/Comite&AwE- de discipline e&AwE-tudiante"
```

I have never seen this way of escaping characters before, and I can't find it anywhere because I don't know what it's called and search engines keep ignoring the "&" in my queries (I've tried quotes and I get the same results).

Comment: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools do not suffer

Comment: A bit too late, I've got my own working solution [here], but will look into integrating or completely using imap_tools in the future.

[here]: https://github.com/polygphys-emilejetzer/outils/blob/889c5b20dec453bba295444f34d989fece0fbc0f/reseau/courriel.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [RFC2060](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2060.html) that describes IMAP, [section 5.1.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2060.html#section-5.1.3) describes how mailboxes should be named, using `&-` to escape `&`, and otherwise using those `&` and `-` as delimiters for base64 encoded values. I have found [a gist](https://gist.github.com/olegbuevich/e7bbb382ec6a4b7d3a504fdd1d963f27) by [Oleg Buevich](https://gist.github.com/olegbuevich) that claims to correctly encode and decode those UTF-7 with modified base64 strings. It works as far as I can tell. For the mailboxes listed in the question, I get:

```
(\HasNoChildren) "/" "Libérations/Libération Bilan"
(\HasNoChildren) "/" "Poly/Comité de discipline étudiante"
```

which are correct.